# Prove that $ A \ $ is invertible if and only if there is a square matrix $ B \ $ such that $ \ (AB+ B^TA ) \ $ is positive definite .

Tags: matrices

Suppose $ A \ $ is a symmetric matrix . Prove that $ A \ $ is invertible  if and only if there is a square matrix $ B \ $ such that $ \ (AB+ B^TA ) \ $ is positive definite .

**Answer:**

Let $ A \ $ be symmetric and non-singular .

Then $ A^{-1} \ $ exists and is also symmetric .

Further $ A^{-1} $ is square , since it is the inverse of a matrix.

Take , $ B=A^{-1} \ $.

Then,

$ AB+B^{T}A=AA^{-1}+(A^{-1})^TA =AA^{-1}+(A^T)^{-1} A=AA^{-1}+A^{-1}A=I+I=2I , \ \ (\because A^T=A  \ \ and \ \ (A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T ) $

Thus,

$ AB+B^TA=2I , \ \ I=indentity \ \ matrix $

Since $ I \ $ is positive definite matrix , $ AB+B^T A $ is positive definite.

**But how to the converse part ?**

**If there is any help ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that $A$ is not invertible. Then $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, and hence there exists some $v \neq 0$ such that $Av=0$.

Then
$$v^T (AB+ B^TA ) v =0$$
which contradicts positive definitedness.

Comment: Is the first part is correct what i did ?

Comment: @mabmath Yes. .